# How to write a batch file to return a WMIC result

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

How do I write a batch file to return true if the manufacturer of the motherboard is `ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.` and return false if it's not using the `wmic` command?

The command is as below:

```
wmic baseboard get Manufacturer
```

and it returns:

> ```
> Manufacturer
> ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
> ```

and I only need to compare the string `ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture the output of the `wmic` command use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
set "BOARD="
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic BaseBoard get Manufacturer
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        set "BOARD=%%J"
    )
)
rem // Compare retrieved string:
if /I "%BOARD%"=="ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC." (
    echo True
) else (
    echo False
)
```

The two nested `for /F` loops are necessary to properly convert the Unicode `wmic` output.

---

However, you could also filter the `wmic` output directly, like this:

```cmd
wmic BaseBoard where "Manufacturer='ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.'" get Manufacturer 2>&1 > nul | find /V "" > nul && (echo False) || (echo True)
```

The [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) clause does the filtering; if no match is found, `No Instance(s) Available.` is returned on the *STD_ERR* stream (handle `2`). The expression `2>&1 > nul` suppresses the *STD_OUT* stream (handle `1`) and [redirects](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) *STD_ERR* to *STD_OUT* instead, so [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) is going to receive it; the search expression `/V ""` finds a match when the stream is not empty. `find` returns an exit code of `0` if a match is found and `1` otherwise; the [operators](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `&&` and `||` check the exit code and execute the respective `echo` command contitionally.